# Doctrine 2.0 Bootstrap?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Ok, so I've got the Doctrine.php file in a folder hierarchy like so:

```
\
  includes\
    Setup.php
    Doctrine\
      Common\
      DBAL\
      ORM\
      Symfony\
      Doctrine.php
```

My setup.php has the following:

```
$rootPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$includePath = getcwd() . "\includes";
ini_set('include_path', '.'.PATH_SEPARATOR.$rootPath.PATH_SEPARATOR.$includePath);

require_once 'includes\Doctrine\Doctrine.php';
```

My Doctrine.php is:

```
<?php
/*
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
 * A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
 * OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
 * SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
 * DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
 * THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
 * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 * This software consists of voluntary contributions made by many individuals
 * and is licensed under the LGPL. For more information, see
 * <http://www.doctrine-project.org>.
 */

require_once 'Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';

$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Doctrine');
$classLoader->register();

$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Symfony', 'Doctrine');
$classLoader->register();

$configFile = getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cli-config.php';

$helperSet = null;
if (file_exists($configFile)) {
    if ( ! is_readable($configFile)) {
        trigger_error(
            'Configuration file [' . $configFile . '] does not have read permission.', E_ERROR
        );
    }

    require $configFile;

    foreach ($GLOBALS as $helperSetCandidate) {
        if ($helperSetCandidate instanceof \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet) {
            $helperSet = $helperSetCandidate;
            break;
        }
    }
}

$helperSet = ($helperSet) ?: new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet();

\Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::run($helperSet);
```

Now when I include my setup.php from an hello world page, I get the following warnings:

```
Notice: Undefined index: argv in C:\xampp\htdocs\SpaceWars\includes\Doctrine\Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput.php on line 53

Warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SpaceWars\includes\Doctrine\Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput.php on line 57
```

Can anyone please guide me what I'm doing wrong? I tried Googling the warnings but can't seem to find anything.

Comment: have you tried using [sandbox](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/tree/master/tools/sandbox) example?

Comment: If I'm completely honest, I'm totally confused as to how/where to put the Doctrine project and how to include this and boot strap it in to my application. I can't even find anything in the documentation telling me how to do it.

Comment: You should post your Doctrine.php file. It needs to be customized for your environment.

Comment: I've added the Doctrine.php source to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The doctrine file you have there is for running the Doctrine tools from the command line. What you need instead is something similar to this:

```
    use Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader,
        Doctrine\ORM\Configuration,
        Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
        Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type,
        Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache,
        Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSqlLogger;


    // include the class loader directly
    require_once __DIR__ . '/Common/ClassLoader.php';

    $doctrineClassLoader = new ClassLoader('Doctrine', __DIR__ . '/../');
    $doctrineClassLoader->register();

    // Set up caches
    $config = new Configuration;
    $cache = new ArrayCache;
    $config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
    $config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);

    // Metadata Driver
    $driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(array('/path/to/entities'));
    $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);

    // Proxy configuration
    $config->setProxyDir(DB_PROXY_DIR);
    $config->setProxyNamespace(DB_PROXY_NAMESPACE);
    $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(DB_PROXY_GEN);

    // Database connection information
    $connectionOptions = array(
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
        'user' => DB_USER,
        'password' => DB_PASS,
        'host' => DB_HOST,
        'dbname' => DB_NAME,
        'port' => DB_PORT
    );

    // Create EntityManager
    $em = EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);
```

The `$em` is the entity manager you use to persist and retrieve entities. This is from the documentation here: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/configuration.html#obtaining-an-entitymanager

**UPDATE** Added use statements at the top of the file. These are required so that the full namespace isn't required when you use the classes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, I'm getting a "Fatal error: Class 'ClassLoader' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\SpaceWars\includes\Doctrine\Doctrine.php on line 6" which is the new ClassLoader('Doctrine'... line :/

Comment: @Martin Blore - I have updated the answer to include `use` statements at the top. These let you use classes without the full namespace.

Comment: Thank again rojoca, just taking a step in to PHP from years of .NET and seem to be failing at understanding the most basics - so might take a step back and get a few of the basics under my belt first.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP Version Running On CGI Not CLI

Please Set Configuration php.ini To { CLI }

Example php.ini :

```
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to On for the CLI SAPI

register_argc_argv = On
```

Answer (score 0):

argv - is a system variable
if you run script from console it must exists