# How to make an SQL table rows as objects in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have SQL DB with some tables. and I would like to know if there is any way that I can build a Class with some fields and functions, and to make instances of this class for each row in this table, and use these objects later in JS code to show the objects in certain way for the user ?
I'm new in web developing, so I may not be clear.. sorry for that.

Comment: this was so helpful.. thanks..

Comment: http://php.net//manual/bg/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13084958/1729885

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is an object relational mapper (ORM) like Propel or Doctrine, for example. The ORM provides the mapping between your PHP Objects and the underlying SQL database.

In order to access these objects in your JavaScript application, you need to transfer them using a suitable text representation. The most common format is [JSON](http://json.org/), which is part of the ECMA standard. Using the text representation, objects can be integrated directly in JavaScript or fetched using AJAX calls.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample code that might provide a useful model.

```
class community {
public $community_id;
public $name;
public $handle;
public $parent_comm_id;
public $shortname;

public static $COMMUNITIES = array();

function __construct($community_id, $name, $handle, $parent_comm_id) {
    $this->community_id = $community_id;
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->handle = $handle;
    $this->parent_comm_id = $parent_comm_id;

    self::$COMMUNITIES[$community_id] = $this;
}


public static function initCommunities() {
    $dbh = $GLOBALS['dbh'];
    $sql = <<< EOF
    select community_id, name, handle, parent_comm_id 
    from community
    inner join handle on community_id = resource_id and resource_type_id = 4
    left join community2community on child_comm_id = community_id
    order by name;  
EOF;

    $result = pg_query($dbh, $sql);
    if (!$result) {
        die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
    }       

    while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
        new community($row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3]);
    }       

    // free memory
    pg_free_result($result);    
}
}
```